# Why does Spark Sql Exclude the Inet Data Type?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a postgres database (9.2) that uses the `inet` type in the schema. I am attempting to write to the postgres with Spark (1.6).

```
df.write.mode(mode).jdbc(db, table, props)
```

I am applying the schema to the df with;

```
context.createDataFrame(rdd, schema())
```

and getting all BatchUpdateException errors described in [SPARK-13286](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13286) due to the schema mismatch. The schema is a StructType of StructFields that require a Spark Sql DataType. Is there a way to make this work with any of the existing Spark Sql Data Types?

Comment: OP did you solve this .? I have the same problem .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does Spark Sql Exclude the Inet Data Type?

Realistically Spark cannot support all the custom types which are used by different JDBC sources (not only RDBMS) out there.

> way to make this work with any of the existing Spark Sql Data Types?

You can use query to cast to the type, which is consumable by Spark (not tested):

```
spark.read.jdbc(url, "(SELECT CAST(inet_col AS TEXT) FROM table) AS t")
```